# How do you integrate Venmo Payments with a React Native IOS App

Tags: ios, react-native, paypal, braintree, venmo

I am currently trying to figure out how I can integrate Venmo as a payment method for a React Native IOS app I am working on. I know this must be possible because UberEats, an app that I believe is also built with React Native, has integrated Venmo as a payment method.

I have looked at the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/articles/guides/payment-methods/venmo#setup) for integrating Venmo into an app or a website and there seems to be 3 different SDKs to choose from (Android v4, IOS v5, or Javascript v3), with none of them being specific to React Native.

Does anyone know how I should go about implementing Venmo payments into the app? Should I be using the Javascript v3 SDK, or should I be using the IOS v5 SDK even though the app is in React Native? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you processing PayPal payments more generally? If you can use a native Braintree SDK from your app, do so. They automate opening the SafariViewController, which is necessary (no webview support)

Comment: So by that do you mean that I should use the IOS SDK for Braintree? If so, how would I go about doing that considering the app codebase is done in React Native?

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of guides available for using Braintree with React Native. See for example [this one.](https://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/how-to-customise-the-braintree-dropin-ui-in-react-native)